# Front end post and upload file, image for users without plugin

Tags: metabox, users, front-end

There are multiple users who have to post their own post on respective post types (like news, reports etc) with feature image upload, extra file (pdf, txt, excel) upload button from the front end which is approve by the admin from backend.

I have solve for feature image but hanging my mind for file upload from front end for the respective post.

I have upload the file also from backend using metabox but no idea how to make it working from frontend to upload.Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to use the Media Library upload?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wp_handle_upload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) in a custom function

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
upload_user_file($_FILES['test_upload']);
}


if ( ! function_exists( 'upload_user_file' ) ) :
    function upload_user_file( $file = array(), $title = false ) {

        require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/admin.php';

        $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));

        if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){

            return false;

        }else{

            $filename = $file_return['file'];

            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'guid' => $file_return['url']
            );

            if($title){
                $attachment['post_title'] = $title;
            }

            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

            $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );

            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

            if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
                return $attachment_id;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this plugin possibly provide what you need? [Frontend Uploader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/).

> This plugin is a simple way for users to submit content to your site. The plugin uses a set of shortcodes to let you create highly customizable submission forms to your posts and pages. Once the content is submitted, it is held for moderation until you approve it.

Comment: no use of plugin please